# Creating a unit test for CORS with xUnit and .Net Core MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, cors, dotnet-httpclient, xunit.net

I want to write a unit test to ensure CORS is on and that a particular WebApi method can only be called from a client that reports to be from a certain domain.

I think I'm running into a common gotcha that's described here, whereby it's not seen as a true cross domain request...

[CORS Gotchas](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas)

The type of unit test would look something like this...

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task CheckCors()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://clientdomain.co.uk/");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri($"http://apidomain.co.uk/api/testcors", UriKind.Absolute));

        // Should be forbidden to call the api
        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }
```

I may have misunderstood things, but can anyone put me right?

Answer (score 2):

First of this isn't a unit test because you are making a call out to some external resource.  Unit tests should have any external dependencies mocked/faked out. This is really an integration test.

Also this isn't really testing your code to configure cors, this is testing that cors actually works.

That being said, I tried writing a unit test for CORS and came up with this.  Given that I have class that configures CORS

```
public static class CorsConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CorsClientUrl"], "*", "*")
        {
            SupportsCredentials = true
        };

        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
}
```

Where my `AppSettings["CorsClientUrl"]` has a value of "https://www.google.com"

So then I want to test that cors is configured after this is called.  All my unit test derive from `SpecificationBase` so that I have a little more BDD style syntax when I write my tests

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class SpecificationBase
{
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        Given();
        When();
    }

    protected virtual void Given()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void When()
    {
    }
}

public class ThenAttribute : TestAttribute
{
}
```

And the ultimate unit tests look like this

```
    public class WhenConfiguringCors : SpecificationBase
    {
        private HttpConfiguration _httpConfiguration;
        private CorsPolicy _corsPolicy;

        protected override void Given()
        {
            _httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
        }

        protected override void When()
        {
            CorsConfig.Register(_httpConfiguration);

            var corsConfig = _httpConfiguration.Properties["MS_CorsPolicyProviderFactoryKey"] as AttributeBasedPolicyProviderFactory;

            _corsPolicy =
                corsConfig.DefaultPolicyProvider.GetCorsPolicyAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(), CancellationToken.None)
                    .Result;
        }

        [Then]
        public void ShouldSetOrigin()
        {
            Assert.That(
                _corsPolicy.Origins.Contains("https://www.google.com"), Is.True);
        }

        [Then]
        public void ShouldSupportCredentials()
        {
            Assert.That(
                _corsPolicy.SupportsCredentials, Is.True);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're right, it's more integration testing, but the source domain is on a customer by customer basis and I want to ensure the functionality is never inadvertently switched off and the domains taken correctly from the other layers

Comment: that's nice code but it doesn't answer my question. It tests that a policy contains a domain but not that the CORS policy is picked up and used. As you rightly said it's more an integration test I was looking for. You also missed looking at that link which is about CORS filters aren't even called when the caller and callee are localhost which I think make it difficult if not impossible to write a test for.

Comment: Exactly.  It tests the code you wrote to setup CORS because you asked for a unit test to verify CORS.  And yes, the definition of CORS contains "Cross-Origin" so calls under the same url and port, aren't cross origins.  For your "integration test" to work, your test would need an origin at your client.  Checking that a certain client can only use a specific origin is completely different test since CORS doesn't care about your client and carries no authentication information.  You would probably need to write an action filter to handle after the CORS pre-flight check passes.